# Why is the._main.dart file generated when the Flutter project file is generated by Android Studio on a MAC computer

Tags: android-studio

Why is the ._main.dart file generated when the Flutter project file is generated by Android Studio on a MAC computer, and how can I remove this superfluous file?
[image]

How to solve this problem?This file is not available on windows computers.